# How is the stack unwound and stack frames identified

Tags: c

Let's say I have this simple program in C.

```
int my_func(int a, int b, int c) //0x4000
{
    int d = 0;
    int e = 0;
    return e+d;
}

int main()
{
    my_func(1,2,3); // 0x5000
    return 0;
}
```

Ignoring the fact that it is essentially all dead code which can be completely optimized away. We'll say that my_func() lives at address 0x4000 and it is being called at address 0x5000.

From my understanding, a c compiler (I understand they can operate differently by vendor) may:

- push c to the stack
- push b to the stack
- push a to the stack
- push 0x5000 to the stack (return address)
- call 0x4000

Then I'm assuming to access a it uses sp (stack pointer) + 1. b is sp+2 and c is sp+3.

Since d and e are on the stack, I'm guessing our stack would now look like this?

- c
- b
- a
- 0x5000
- d
- e

When we get to the end of the function.

- Does it then pop e and d off the stack?
- Then... push e+d? Or save it to a register to be used after return?
- Return to 0x5000 because it's the top of the stack?
- Then pop the return address (0x5000) and a, b and c?

I'm guessing this is why old c required all the variables to be declared at the top of a function so that the compiler could count the number of pops it needed to perform at the end of the function?

I understand that it could have stored 0x5000 in a register, but a C program is able to go multiple levels deep into many functions and there are only so many registers...

Thanks!

Comment: Looks quite good; where exactly parameters and return values are passed is defined by the ABI of the platform. On many platforms the result of a function is for example not pushed on the stack, but passed in a register. Or the first three arguments are passed in registers, anything in excess is put on the stack... And so on...

Comment: Too short to be an answer, but it's up to the calling convention for the function. In C, you can pass any number of parameters to a function, so generally caller is responsible for restoring stack pointer after the call. As for returned values, that depends on calling convention too. Note that C standard itself doesn't even specify "stack", it's just what most platforms have and is the usual way to pass and return values which don't fit to registers.

Comment: One way to investigate what *your* compiler does, is to write different functions and call them in C code, then ask compiler to produce assembly code (or run under debugger and use its disassembler). Just be sure to turn off all optimisations, or the code might be hard to understand and might do unexpected things (inline function calls, eliminate code which has no effect, then reorder the assembly instructions, etc).

Comment: A C compiler is allowed to optimize to the point that it does not use any call stack (per the [as-if rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/As-if_rule)). BTW, on most systems, some arguments are passed in registers (so not pushed on the stack). Read about [calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention)

Comment: Regarding the variables on the top of the function, it was the convention in the past, no because of the stack.

Comment: you might like https://godbolt.org to experiment with assembly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In default calling convention** for `C`, caller frees function argument after return from function. But function itself manages its own variables on stack. For example here is your code in assembly without any optimization:

```
my_func:
  push ebp                      // +
  mov ebp, esp                  // These 2 lines prepare function stack
  sub esp, 16                   // reserve memory for local variables
  mov DWORD PTR [ebp-4], 0
  mov DWORD PTR [ebp-8], 0
  mov edx, DWORD PTR [ebp-8]
  mov eax, DWORD PTR [ebp-4]
  add eax, edx                  // <--return value in eax
  leave                         // return esp to what it was at start of function
  ret                           // return to caller
main:
  push ebp
  mov ebp, esp
  push 3
  push 2
  push 1
  call my_func
  add esp, 12                   // <- return esp to what it was before pushing arguments
  mov eax, 0
  leave
  ret
```

As you see, there is a `add esp, 12` in `main` for returning `esp` as it was before pushing arguments. In `my_func` there is a pair like this:

```
  push ebp
  mov ebp, esp
  sub esp, 16 // <--- size of stack
  ...
  leave
  ret
```

This pair set is used for reserving some memory as stack. `leave` reverses the effect of `push ebp/move ebp,esp`. And function used `ebp` for accessing its arguments and stack-allocated variables. Return value is always in `eax`.

**A quick allocated stack size note:** 
As you see, in function, there is a `add esp, 16` instruction even though you only keep 2 variable of type `int` on stack which has a total size of 8 bytes. It is because stack size is aligned to specific boundaries (At least with default compile options). If you add 2 more `int` variables to `my_func`, this instruction is still `add esp, 16`, because total stack is still in 16 byte alignment. But if you add a 3rd variable of `int`, this instruction becomes `add esp, 32`. This alignment can be configured by `-mpreferred-stack-boundary` option in `GCC`.

By the way, all of these are for 32-bit compilation of code.In contrast, you normally never pass argument via stack pushing in 64-bit and you pass them through registers. As mentioned in comment, in 64-bit arguments are only passed through stack starting 5th argument[(on microsoft x64 calling convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#x86-64_calling_conventions)).

**Update:**

From **default calling convention**, In mean `cdecl` which is normally used  when you compile your code for x86, without any compiler options or specific function attributes. If you change function call to `stdcall` as an example, all these will change.

Comment: Note in 64-bit: First 6 arguments are passed in registers `rdi`, `rsi`, `rdx`, `rcx`, `r8`, `r9`. The rest are pushed onto the stack, starting from the 7th argument.

Comment: @iBug I had `normally never` because I meant it is rare to have 7+ arguments... :D But I will add that too.

Comment: @iBug btw, where did you see 7th? I though it was 5th and I checked and it was like that in microsoft x64 calling convention.

Comment: Oh, it was unclear after all. I was right looking at the System V ABI for x86-64.

Comment: Thanks, this is awesome! One question I have is that line 4 says it is reserving memory for local variables. Why does it reserve 16 more bytes when d and e are using only 8 total?

Comment: @Questionable stack size is aligned on specific boundries. if you add 2 more int too, instruction is still `add esp,16`, but if you add 3rd one, it becomes `add esp,32`.

Comment: You could qualify "default calling convention" a bit more at the start (especially since you have bolded it), as there is really no default. I mean like, default calling convention of *what* platform or ABI?

Comment: @hyde I meant for x86. All famous compilers compile like that for x86 at least. From default,I meant without any compiler option.

Comment: @hyde even though if you compile code as `stdcall`, it releases stack in function.